# Сборка libpng без определенных опций

Tags: cmake, makefile, libpng

Привествую.
Мне нужно собрать libpng без опции `PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED`, чтобы в итоге, в файле pnglibconf.h строка `#define PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED` была закомментирована. Исходя из написанного в файле pnglibconf.dfa (лежит рядом с исходниками)

> 2) Add definitions of the settings you want to change to
>   CPPFLAGS; for example:
>
> -DPNG_DEFAULT_READ_MACROS=0

Я скачал исходники, сгененрировал проектные файлы путем простого выполнения `cmake` (хотя пробовал и `cmake .. -DCMAKE_CPP_FLAGS="-DPNG_NO_READ_eXIf"`), затем запустил `make` (но пробовал и `make CPPFLAGS="-DPNG_NO_READ_eXIf"`).
В итоге ничего не помогло, эта опция все еще есть в .h файле.
Я так же пробовал с помощью этого примера изменить значение опции `-DPNG_DEFAULT_READ_MACROS` с 1 на 0, чтобы просто убедиться, что приведенный метод работает, но не вышло.

Если кто сталкивался с пользовательской сборкой libpng, подскажите как у вас это получилось?

Comment: определение этого макроса встречается только в одном месте: `scripts/pnglibconf.h.prebuilt`. уберите его и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Нет, там все намного сложнее. Все эти макросы генерируются автоматически на основании того, что написано в `pnglibconf.dfa`. Я пробовал заккоментировать эти define в том файле, что вы указали, однако это ни на что не повлияло.

Comment: можно полностью убрать все три макроса для exif, если добавить в `scripts/pnglibconf.dfa` после `chunk eXIf` слово `disabled`. тогда после `$ make pnglibconf.h` все три макроса будут undefined.

Comment: Видимо, через CMake это сделать нельзя. Попробуйте собирать с помощью autotools и там поискать возможность переопределить этот дефайн.

Comment: отключить только read_exif можно, добавив в `scripts/pnglibconf.dfa` строку `option READ_eXIf off`

Comment: @arrowd, тут дело не в том, кто сгенерирует makefile — cmake или configure. тут речь про генерацию конкретного файла pnglibconf.h. генерируется он гремучей смесью из вызовов компилятора и awk. и повлиять на процесс, насколько вижу, можно только содержимым исходных файлов, из которых и происходит генерация.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня все автоматически собирается через jenkins, и исходники libpng выкачиваются с репозиторя libpng. Но я решил сделать скрипт, который будет вызываться перед сборкой и добавлять в конец `scripts/pnglibconf.dfa` строку `option READ_eXIf off`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько я вижу, такая «тонкая» настройка не конфигурируема при сборке.

отключить её можно, например, добавив строку

```
option READ_eXIf off
```

в конец файла `scripts/pnglibconf.dfa`.

тогда файл `pnglibconf.h` сгенерируется с отключением этого макроса:

```
$ make pnglibconf.h
...
$ grep -i exif pnglibconf.h 
/*#undef PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED*/
#define PNG_WRITE_eXIf_SUPPORTED
#define PNG_eXIf_SUPPORTED
```